# JMock - how to mock console output

Tags: java, junit, jmock

This post is similar to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256119/jmock-how-to-automate-mock-out-console-user-input)

I have a console app that expects both user input and has responsive user output. I am writing some unit tests for it to make sure that the code works properly. I need to be able to make sure that the output and input for it are what I expect them to be.

Essentially, I have a main method being tested that asks for a file or input. In my test, I use `System.setOut` and `System.setIn` to set those to context.mock versions of PrintStream and InputStream objects respectively. I don't care about what `System.out.println` calls get made until I have to test the actual processing of the program data, when it outputs its results to the console. So to summarize:

Here's my source being tested (something close, I trimmed much out): [http://ideone.com/rptC0](http://ideone.com/Tmh1M)

Here's what I have in my mocking procedure: [http://ideone.com/VkvqM](http://ideone.com/QnL2a)

And here's the exception that I'm getting: [ideone.com/OEOS8](http://ideone.com/OEOS8)

As you can clearly see in my expectations, I'm explicitly saying that I was planning to print the exact same string out, and I specified that in my expectations. But the exception says that it was unexpected. I don't understand...

Comment: If you're going to post linked code, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) will probably get you better answers quicker...

Comment: you're right, sorry, repost with SSCCE below.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not self-contained (several other classes are needed such as `Word` and `WordFrequency`) nor correct - `main` doesn't compile because it uses type 'bool' and calls an undefined method `inputReadFailure`

Comment: Oh crap... err. I wasn't finished editing the link when you took it. Hold on, I'll fix those, I just finished fixing them...

Comment: OK, I have edited my copy to get it working and I think I see the problem - see my comment below (will also edit the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMock expects you to declare the Expectations using `context.checking()` *then* call the code under test, *then* call `context.assertIsSatisfied()` (although sometimes the last step is done implicitly if using an appropriate test runner).

You seem to be immediately calling `context.assertIsSatisfied()` before running any code.

Also, the code you posted uses the variable `mn` which does not appear to be defined - is that actually the code you are running? Or should that variable be `mockIn` instead?

**Updated**: OK, the problem is probably that you are trying to mock a static method - JMock doesn't support this - see [jmock mocking a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218813/jmock-mocking-a-static-method) . See particularly the answer from Steve Freeman, who is one of the JMock authors.

**Updated 2**: I would try something like this, setting an expectation in the @Before setup:

```
@Before
public void setMinimalMockingExpectations() throws IOException
{
    oldIn = System.in;
    oldOut = System.out;
    pipe = new PipedOutputStream();
    testIn = new PipedInputStream(pipe);
    mockOut = context.mock(PrintStream.class);
    System.setOut(mockOut);
    System.setIn(testIn);

    expectQuestion();
}

private void expectQuestion()
{
    Expectations exp = new Expectations()
    {
        {
            one(mockOut).println(main.QUESTION);
        }
    };
    context.checking(exp);

}

@After
public void reset()
{
    System.setIn(oldIn);
    System.setOut(oldOut);
}

@Test
public void fileChoiceReturnsFalse() throws IOException
{
    String FILE = "F\n";
    pipe.write(FILE.getBytes());

    assertFalse(main.promptStringOrFile());

    context.assertIsSatisfied(); // can avoid this call by using the right
                                    // test runner
}
```

and create two similar tests to check behaviour for input "I" and any other input (for which the question should be repeated once).

The `promptStringOrFile()` method is probably clearer if you use `BufferedReader.readLine()` rather than worrying about chars.

Comment: well I rearranged it and it still didn't work, while using the mn variable. the mn variable is a mocked version of the class main that I am trying to test over.

Here's the [code](http://ideone.com/rptC0)

Here's the [test](http://ideone.com/VkvqM)

Comment: Ah, the problem is that you're trying to mock a static method. JMock doesn't support this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218813/jmock-mocking-a-static-method

Comment: Actually, I edited it and got a bit further... now I'm having trouble with the parameters on the arguments to a read function that accepts an array. I don't know how to do it. [Code](http://ideone.com/pPwCf),[tests](http://ideone.com/MwvzN) 
[Stack trace](
http://pastebin.com/WRMPT3Aj)

Comment: Sorry about that. There doesn't seem to be a way in ideone to have a public piece of code that is also considered owned by the user...
I thought you would be able to see them even if they were considered owned by me. I changed the visibility however.